get error in installing next@canary npm error peer react@"19.0.0-rc.0" from next@15.0.0-canary.75
I have problem with enable ppr in nextjs 14
i got some error in installing next@canary
i try to install next@canary
npm i next@canary

npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: todo@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^18.3.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"19.0.0-rc.0" from next@15.0.0-canary.75
npm error node_modules/next
npm error   next@"15.0.0-canary.75" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

i try this with -f but show this error again when npm run dev

i try to delete node_modules but not work

did you find a solution ?
